# URL Schema for Long Running Operation in Web Application

Tags: url

In our web application we have some pages that may take long time to generate. The reason is that they need information that takes between few seconds and few minutes to calculate. Once the data is calculated it is cached and access is very fast.

During the time the system calculate the information we want to show the user some message and not just leave the browser spinning.

The question is how to architect the URL schema:

1. Use the same URLs and return a different content that show the "loading" sign and reload every few seconds.
2. Redirect the client (302 temporary) to another URL which redirect the client back to the real URL once the information is ready.

Please take into account we have several URLs that use that same data:

- /index/{id}
- /export/{id}

So using option 1 will keep the URL schema simpler but will not be so friendly with output cache and cache in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decide to use option #1 and use the same URL.
The main reason for doing that is that it's much easier to support url parameters the user enter when the long operation had to be done. If I would have redirect to another URL I had to keep those parameters.
I do ensure to update cache headers to ensure the client will not cache the "loading" screen.